# Вызов View не из главного потока

Tags: java, android, realm

У меня есть 2 класса: `MainActivity`, `ChatsCommunicator` и интерфейс `IView`.

`MainActivity` реализовывает `IView` интерфейс. В интерфейсе есть метод `onGetChatsMethod(List<ChatsDialogModel> chatsModel)`, который переопределяет `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onGetChatsSuccess(final RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsList) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate, getChatsByCount(17) finish ");
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mChatsRV.setAdapter(new ChatsAdapter(chatsList));
        }
    });
}
```

`ChatsCommunicator` в свою очередь отправляет тот `RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsList`:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           ChatsRepository chatsRepository = new ChatsRepository();
           RealmResults<ChatsModel> realmResults = chatsRepository.getAllRecords();

           chatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(chatsModel, false);
       }
}).start();
```

Как видите, действия с `RecyclerView` делаются в методе `runOnUiThread`. А чтение и отправка данных из `Realm` в новом потоке.

До этого не было ни `runOnUiThread` ни `Thread`, но главный поток тормозил пока данные брались из базы. А сейчас после нового потока в `ChatsCommunicator` `MainActivity` шустро работает. 
Но у меня есть еще несколько методов которые работают в главном потоке и тоже вызывают `chatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(RealmResults<ChatsModel> chatsList)`, а для них `runOnUiThread` не нужен и вообще метод `runOnUiThread` мне глаза режет.

Вопрос: как можно в `MainActivity` обойтись без `runOnUiThread` или в `ChatsCommunicator` без `new Thread()`?

**UPD:**

Я пробовал считывать данные из `Realm` с методом `findAllAsync()` но тогда `chatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(chatsModel, false);` все равно срабатывает не ожидая ответа от базы.

Answer (score 2):

Эта задача легко решается с использованием `rxJava` так:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(ChatsModel.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
    .filter(RealmResult::isLoaded)
    .filter(RealmResult::isValid)
    .subscribe(results -> chatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(chatsModel, false));
```

Вызовите этот код из основного потока и результат выборки будет передан в колбэк в основном же потоке каждый раз при изменении выборки. При этом вам не надо создавать потоки, вызывать `runOnuiThread` и выборка из БД будет не в основном потоке сделана.

Comment: Все, завербовали!!!)

Comment: @DevOma, mission completed)